# Interface not appearing (Dockerfile and X11)

Tags: docker, dockerfile, x11

I'm creating a Dockerfile that starts a java app that I created, nothing too complex as it is my first Docker project.

It's for school, so I have some restriction :

- I have to start from debian:latest version
- I can only use one and only dockerfile.

This is what I have currently :

```
FROM debian:latest

# Installer les dépendances nécessaires
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    openjdk-17-jdk \
    openjdk-17-jre \
    libxext6 \
    libxrender1 \
    libxtst6 \
    xauth \
    xvfb

# Copier les fichiers
COPY ./ihmgui.jar ./paquetage_classe/

# On crée une variable d'environnement
ENV CLASSPATH=/paquetage_classe/:/paquetage_classe/ihmgui.jar

# Copier les fichiers Java
COPY ./EchecSolitaire/*.java /paquetage_java/
COPY ./EchecSolitaire/Metier/*.java /paquetage_java/
COPY ./EchecSolitaire/Metier/Piece/*.java /paquetage_java/

# Copier les fichiers Data et Images
COPY ./EchecSolitaire/data/*.txt /paquetage_java/data/
COPY ./EchecSolitaire/Images/*.gif /paquetage_java/Images/

# Compiler le code source
WORKDIR /paquetage_java
RUN javac *.java -encoding utf8 -d ../paquetage_classe/

RUN groupadd -g 1000 lyonn
RUN useradd -d /home/lyonn -s /bin/bash -m lyonn -u 1000 -g 1000
USER lyonn
ENV HOME /home/lyonn

# Définir la commande par défaut
CMD xvfb-run -a java EchecSolitaire.Controleur
```

I'm on windows, so I'm using Xming. I'm using also this commande to create and start my docker :

`docker build -t echecsolitaire .`
`docker run --rm -it -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -e DISPLAY=host.docker.internal:0 echecsolitaire`

No error happened, but nothing is on my screen.

Comment: Xvfb creates an invisible display. You shouldn't be using it when you want a visible one; even if everything else were correct, the `xvfb-run` would be enough to cause the problem described.

Comment: Beyond that, you need to _either_ plumb through a UNIX socket _or_ include a hostname in your DISPLAY, not both. And on Windows, I don't think UNIX sockets are an option (on a Linuxy system you might have a local `/tmp/.X11-unix` to plumb into the container with a bind mount, but that's not where you are).

Comment: That all being the case, I'd argue that you'd do yourself a favor running Docker in a Linux VM and only worry about getting it to work directly on a Windows host after you're successfully got this going in the more native platform. Walk before you run, &c.